# MVC Sitecore View pass attribute to property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore-mvc

So my problem is like this. In sitecore view i can write someting like this:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field(PictureID.ToString(), Model.Person.Item, cssClass: "img-responsive");
```

which will get me the HtmlString for the field with ID PictureID on the item Model.Person.Item and in that HtmlString i will have a cssClass added. So the result will be something like

```
<img src="xxxx" class="img-responsive"/>
```

For this View the Model will be RenderingModel. But what if i have a Person as a model and this person would have a property called Picture which will be retrieved somewhere in the code behind so that in the view i would have

```
@Model.Picture
```

How do i connect the view, controller and model so that from the view i send somehow the cssClass that i want that Picture to have when the HtmlString is returned.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the class name to the renderField pipeline.

So if Model.Picture is a HtmlString containing the output of the renderField pipeline the class name cannot be decided dynamically in the View but need to be set in the Model (it can be discussed if this is a nice approach).

Anyway when you create your model you can pass the class name into the renderField pipeline as follows:

```
  var renderFieldArgs = new RenderFieldArgs
  {
    Item = this.Item,
    FieldName = "PICTURE FIELD ID"
  };
  TypeHelper.CopyProperties(parameters, new {@class = "img-responsive"} );
  CorePipeline.Run("renderField", renderFieldArgs);
  return new HtmlString(renderFieldArgs.Result.FirstPart);
```

This will mean that Model.Picture always will have the same class name.

Otherwise you could have a method on your Model class accepting a class name string as parameter. Something like

```
  public HtmlString GetPictureMarkup(string className)
  {
      var renderFieldArgs = new RenderFieldArgs
      {
        Item = this.Item,
        FieldName = "PICTURE FIELD ID"
      };
      TypeHelper.CopyProperties(parameters, new {@class = className} );
      CorePipeline.Run("renderField", renderFieldArgs);
      return new HtmlString(renderFieldArgs.Result.FirstPart);
  }
```

Hope it helps.